# How to launch test with Viper?

Tags: populus, vyper

I would like to switch the smart contract compiler from Solidity to Viper. I'm following the Viper support page found in Populus documentation.

This is what I get at the final step:

```
Mac:tutorial admin$ py.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 397, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
plugin = ep.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2404, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2427, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 875, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pytest 3.3.1 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pytest!=3.3.*,>=2.7.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/py.test", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 50, in main
config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 160, in _prepareconfig
pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 196, in _multicall
gen.send(outcome)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 68, in pytest_cmdline_parse
config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 76, in get_result
raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 943, in pytest_cmdline_parse
self.parse(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 1108, in parse
self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 1071, in _preparse
self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints('pytest11')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 402, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
"Plugin %r could not be loaded: %s!" % (ep.name, e))
pluggy.PluginValidationError: Plugin 'ethereum' could not be loaded: (pytest 3.3.1 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pytest!=3.3.*,>=2.7.2'))!
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE

I don't know why but py.test didn't work any longer after installing Viper.
That creates version conflicts solved with:

```
 pip3 install 'pytest!=3.3.*,>=2.7.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the docs here @ http://viper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-vyper.html? They might be updated. Took me a while but got it going after a good effort. Let me know if not and I'll try to help!